# On src change even if src is not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple image like this:

`<img id="ddd" src="/someimage.jpg" /> <!-- valid image -->`

Now on button click i change it like this:

```
<script>
    function Change() {
        $("#ddd").prop("src", "/someOtherImage.jpg"); <!-- valid image -->
    }
</script>
```

and besides that i listen to when it is changed like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#ddd").on("load", function() {
            alert("changed");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and like this it works but it doesn't work when i set it to invalid image like this:

```
<script>
    function Change1() {
        $("#ddd").prop("src", "/savsavsa.jpg"); <!-- invalid image -->
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    function Change1() {
        $("#ddd").prop("src", "none"); <!-- invalid image -->
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    function Change1() {
        $("#ddd").prop("src", "#"); <!-- invalid image -->
    }
</script>
```

in none of 3 above chages it fires `load` event. I tried with `change` event but also not working. When i inspect that `img` **it does change**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the `error` event will be fired if the image source points to an invalid resource, so you can use:

```js
function srcChangedListener() {
    alert("changed");
}
$(function() {
    $("#ddd").on("load", srcChangedListener);
    $("#ddd").on("error", srcChangedListener);
});
```

**However**, these events will only fire *after the resource is fetched from the server*. If you want a faster approach, use `MutationObserver`.

Answer (score 2):

The `load` event fires when the image **loads**, not when the `src` is changed.

If you change the src to something that doesn't make an image load successfully then it is natural that there is no `load` event.

Try the `error` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to listen `load` event on invalid image. Since there's no image, there would be no `load` event.

If you primarily want to check for src attribute change, then you may trigger custom event:

```
var imgSrc = null;
$(function(){
  var imageSrc = $('#ddd').attr('src');
  if (imageSrc != imgSrc) {
   $('#ddd').trigger('srcChange');
  }
})

// listen for the change:
$('#ddd').on('srcChange', function() {
  console.log('src changed');
});
```

If you want to check src attribute change on occurrence then you may store old value in localStorage and check for the change with that value or check for the change by triggering on interval.